# Проблема с отправкой Telegram-ботом InlineQueryResultPhoto

Tags: telegram-bot, telegram

```php
[
'type' => "photo",
'id' => $id,
'title' => $title,
'photo_url' => "https://example.com/1.jpg",
'thumb_url' => "https://example.com/1_small.jpg"
]
```

Отправляю такой InlineQueryResultPhoto. Telegram говорит, что всё ок, но у пользователя ничего не отображается. В чём дело?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказалось, параметры `photo_width` и `photo_height`, которые в документации отмечены как необязательные, всё-таки нужно передавать.

https://www.reddit.com/r/TelegramBots/comments/3zka60/telegram_inlinequeryresultphoto_issues/